# Styling Drop Down Menu Positioned to the Right

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

So bascially, I'm working on a jquery menu that has a fixed position on the top right of a page. The "Navigation" box will always be displayed. When clicked, it expands to display Applications, Forum, Guilds and Projects". And when a sub menu is clicked, it will expand as well as shown with Applications.

http://i46.tinypic.com/xp6gox.png

I can't get the css to look like this image. A few details are 6px padding in each "boxes", 3px bottom margin under them, sub-menu will have gray backgrounds, the width of each box is dependent on the width of it's text.

Here is the actual HTML/CSS www.jsfiddle.net/3HAKX/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS will look like:

`www.jsfiddle.net/3HAKX/1/`

Do you want a JS script for a drop down menu too?

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there any way to make it so that when I add padding, it doesn't go on top of each other?

Also, I'm using a jquery menu.
http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if I understood your question. But here is the code how I would accomplish that.

```
<ul id="accordion">
            <li>
                <a href="#recent" class="heading">Application</a>
                                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">January 2009</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">December 2008</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">November 2008</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">October 2008</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">September 2008</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#archive" class="heading">Forum</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">January 2009</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">December 2008</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">November 2008</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">October 2008</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">September 2008</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#archive" class="heading">Guilds</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">January 2009</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">December 2008</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">November 2008</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">October 2008</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">September 2008</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#archive" class="heading">Projects</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">January 2009</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">December 2008</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">November 2008</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">October 2008</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">September 2008</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

CSS

```
ul#accordion{
float:right;
}
ul#accordion, ul#accordion ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; }
ul#accordion a.heading { 
    color: black;
    display: block;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right:30px;
}
ul#accordion li ul a { font-size:14px;color: black; text-decoration: none;}
ul#accordion li ul a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

#accordion li ul { display: none; }
#accordion li.current ul { display: block; }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#accordion a.heading').click(function() {
        $(this).css('outline','none');
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('current')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp('slow',function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
            });
        } else {
            $('ul#accordion li.current ul').slideUp('slow',function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
            });
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('slow',function() {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SGDDB/5/)

Comment: They're both essentially doing the same, my issue is just that I can't get the list to align to the right side of the page properly. When adding a 6px padding the boxes of black and gray go on top of one another. Also I want it so that it can have a 3px margin and a bottom without adding any on the top (i.e, margin : 3px 0 3px)

Comment: Hi, I have fixed the problem I had earlier, but that came with a new one. If you click on "Guilds" or "Projects", the list becomes disorganized. http://jsfiddle.net/Nu5Wt/1/